# Wallet transfer status stuck

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, multibit, unconfirmed-transactions, sending

So, I'm just starting out with bitcoin. I bought a little bit and moved it to my local wallet. Once confirmations started to arrive on that transaction, I moved a part of those bitcoins to a bitsquare wallet.

The amount was deducted ok from my first wallet, and I was able to use the amount in bitsquare for a deposit. But the status of the transmission/transaction is stuck in "sending" for two days. Since the coins i received the status has changed from "receiving" to "received" I'm thinking this one should have changed to "sent" by now. It says "seen by # peers", but nothing about confirmations.

My question then: Is this a problem? Should the status have changed to "sent" along with confirmations? Was there some process I needed to set up before sending?

(More on what I did): I am using MultiBit. After getting my coins with a few confirmations, I clicked "Send", wrote an wallet address from my bitsquare wallet, and clicked send. I read something about transaction fees and my wallet preferences is set to 0.1 mBTC (I wonder if this setting is ok).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using MultiBit Classic, you might want to consider upgrading to MultiBit HD, because the former is almost 1.5 years old.

Comment: The file link that was installed on my computer says Multibit HD. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not saying that it's confirmed because it isn't confirmed. See [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Your fee is pretty low at 40 satoshi/byte, so according to [this chart](https://bitcoinfees.21.co/), you should be using a fee 2.5x times higher if you want your transaction to confirm within a day.

Comment: Does that mean it is still going to get confirmed, it is just going to take a long time?  How does 0.1 mBTC become 40 satoshi? I thought 0.1 mBTC converted to 1000 satoshi...

Comment: Most transactions are ~250 bytes, so 0.1mBTC * (1 BTC/1000 mBTC) * (1e8 satoshi/1 BTC) / 250 bytes = 40 satoshi/byte. 0.1 mBTC = 10000 satoshi.

Comment: OH! For some reason I read satoshi/byte as one name (meaning I thought byte was another name for satoshi here). I had a low fee thinking it was high. Thank you!!!